# Control selection/browsing in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, selection, jtextpane

I have a `JTestPane` containing some text (obviously). When browsing the text using the keyboard, one typically uses control + right arrow to skip whole words. The default behavior in `JTestPane` consists in putting the caret right before the first character of the next word.

For example, let's consider the sentence "This is a sentence". Starting from postion 0, if I skip "This" and go to the next word (using CTRL+RIGHT), the caret will be in position 5, i.e. right before "is".

This is fine for browsing, but I don't like this behavior for text selection. In the application I'm working on, it would be much better if, when using SHFT+CTRL+RIGHT, I was selecting only "This" (without the extra space) rather than "This ", as it is by default. In other words, I want to select characters 0-3 instead of 0-4.

I didn't find much information about how to tweak Swing in order to get this kind of result. Up to now, I've tried registering a `CaretListener` to the `JTestPane` and manually shortening the selection in order to remove the trailing space when necessary. It didn't feel right though, and it didn't work well neither, since it prevented from selecting multiple words.

So, if anyone can point me in the right direction, I'll be more than happy.

Comment: You'll need to override the key bindings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swing uses Key Binding to invoke an Action when a certain KeyStroke is invoked. See [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for a list of these bindings. As you can see the `selection-next-word` Action is invoked in this case, so you would need to provide a custom Action.

You could look at the source code of the `DefaultEditorKit` - to see how this is implemented and just make the selection 1 less.

Or maybe you can use the [Wrapping Actions](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/wrapping-actions/) concept to wrap the original Action and then just invoke the setSelection() method of JTextPane to reset the selection to be 1 less than you need. Not sure what the easier approach will be.

Answer (score 0):

So, I followed camickr's advice and changed the `Action` associated to `selection-next-word`. For those interested, here's what I did exactly.

First, I retrieved the source code of the inner class `DefaultEditorKit.NextWordAction`, which is called for both skipping (when browsing) and selecting words. I then copied it to define my own version, and modified its `actionPerformed` method in the following way.

The method contains the instruction `offs = Utilities.getNextWord(target, offs);`, which corresponds to the processing of the caret position for the begining of the next word. Variable `target` is the considered `JTextComponent` and `offs` is the current caret position. After the method call, `offs` contains the position of the begining of the next word.

So, I added the following code right *after* this line:

```
        // remove trailing space from selection 
        if(offs>0)          
        {   String c = target.getText(offs-1, 1);
            if(c.equals(" "))
                offs = offs - 1;
        }
        // remove trailing "'s" from selection 
        if(offs>1)
        {   String c = target.getText(offs-2, 2);
            if(c.equals("'s"))
                offs = offs - 2;
        }
```

As you can see, it corrects `offs` so that it is located before the trailing space. I also want it to be before any 's (as in the mark of genitive, e.g. Vincent**'s** bike), hence the second part of my source code (this additional feature was not specified in my original question).

However, with this sole modification, a new problem appears: it is now impossible to select several consecutive words. When hitting SHFT+CTRL+RIGHT several times, the selection gets stuck on the first word.

So, to avoid this, I added the following code right *before* the previously mentioned line (the `getNextWord` call):

```
        // check for trailing "'"
        if(offs<end-2)
        {   String c = target.getText(offs, 2);
            if(c.equals("'s"))
                offs = offs + 2;
        }
        // check for trailing space
        if(offs<end-1)
        {   String c = target.getText(offs, 1);
            if(c.equals(" "))
                offs = offs + 1;
        }
```

Now, it works fine, this is exactly what I wanted. Many thanks to camickr for his help.